# Is it possible to define an array of structures or objects in VBA?

Tags: arrays, object, excel, vba

I have to implement something in an Excel macro (yuk!), for which I would like to use an array of structures or objects. (Is this even possible at all in Excel VBA?)

The problem is, I can only find extremely meager documentation. Can someone please provide some pointers to good VBA documentation, or a suggestion about using VBA structures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps a Type structure is what you're looking for?

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx (scroll down a little)

Then I suppose you would use this in combination with VBA arrays.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm

Hope that helps a little.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely goes in the right direction, at least!